# User input wont create a vector output (matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm new to Matlab so apologies for such a basic question!
I'm trying to create a line in a function that will create a vector output. E.g I want the user to specify that they want a vector `x = [1:5]` with the user input being `1:5`

So far I've tried:

```
x = input('Specify range of x values e.g [1:5]>');
```

This gives the prompt but when I press enter nothing happens- no vectors are created and stored.

How do I fix this?

Comment: the line works exactly, how it should. The prompt appears, you type "1:5" and you get a vector `x=[1 2 3 4 5]` - what do you expect?

Comment: Ah okay so if it's doing exactly as it's supposed then may I ask a different question- how do I create a prompt that will create a vector output called x which will contain the input range?

Comment: You want a string? I really don't understand. Please tell what exactly you want to see in the command prompt or how the resulting variable in the workspace should look like.

Comment: do you want `x` to be [1 2 3 4 5] or do you want (what I assume) `x` to be '1:5'?

Comment: Thank you for your patience!In the command window when I run the function I'm making I want to see a prompt come up saying 'specify range of x values' at which point the user will input a range say 1:5 or -20:100 and after pressing enter a vector will be created called x that contains the values input (e.g. 1  2 3 4 5 if input is [1:5])

Comment: but that is what is happening? is it possible that you declared `x` differently before? try `clear x` before you run the script. `Specify range of x values e.g [1:5]>1:5` or even `Specify range of x values e.g [1:5]>[1:5]` will give you a variable `x` in the workspace with [1 2 3 4 5]

Comment: bjoern I want `x = [1 2 3 4 5]`. thewaywewalk, I've cleared using clearall and I've restarted the programme- still wont create an x variable :/

Comment: How do you know the `x` variable is not created? Do you get any error? What happen if you just type `x` after input?

Comment: Also if you omit semicolumn `;` character at the end of your command you should the output vector right in the command line.

Comment: I think the `x` variable isn't created because I can't see it in the workspace. I want to suppress the output because in practice the array I'll create will be very large.

Comment: If you run it in a function, the variable is created, then goes out of scope when the function exits, so you won't see it in the global workspace.  Basic debug to discover this would include: try the line at the command prompt, display the contents of x right after it is produced, directly set x equal to your desired value and see what happens, etc.  If something doesn't work, try different stuff.